AWS CodeBuild kubectl apply: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation
I am trying to deploy an ECR image on EKS using CodeBuild.
This is my build:
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - aws sts get-caller-identity
      - echo Deploying to Amazon EKS...
      - aws eks --region eu-north-1 update-kubeconfig --name my-eks-cluster --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-ID>:role/ecr2eks_diy
      - kubectl apply -f ../kubernetes

Here are some logs:
Running command aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "<USER-ID>",
    "Account": "<ACCOUNT-ID>",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::<ACCOUNT-ID>:assumed-role/ecr2eks_diy/AWSCodeBuild-410d9d6f-6c36-4106-a6d0-a1959c1ae814"
}

Running command kubectl apply -f ../kubernetes
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: <USER-ID> is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-ID>:role/ecr2eks_diy
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable aws failed with exit code 254

My CodeBuild uses the custom role ecr2eks_diy.
It has AdministratorAccess.
It has the following trust policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-ID>:user/<USERNAME>"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

My  also has AdministratorAccess.
It also has the following inline permit:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-ID>:role/ecr2eks_diy"
        }
    ]
}

In my EKS i have enabled the authentication method EKS-API.
I have 2 entries in the IAM-Prinzipal-ARN:
arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-ID>:role/ecr2eks_diy and arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-ID>:user/<USERNAME>
